# How do "pinned" pages in Linux present (or actually "pin") themselves

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am using `get_user_pages` in a Linux kernel driver to pin memory for the purposes of [hardware] DMA. It all *seems* to work fine - but I am having a hard time proving that the "pinning" is doing the proper thing.

When I inspect the flags on the physical pages after doing `get_user_pages` - the pages don't appear "locked" (as one might think they should be). In fact, I see no difference between the flags of otherwise "active" pages vs. those I have "pinned" via `get_user_pages`.

The *only* difference I see is that get_user_pages has taken a *refcount* on the page. So I guess my question is - is holding this reference *alone* sufficient to guarantee that this page will never be swapped-out, moved, or that my user-space's vaddr will still/always reference the same underlying page?

All the driver source I can find seems to use this mechanism, and documentation seems to indicate that this is the correct way - but I am having a hard time "proving" that this will give me the correct, reliable, intended behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Holding a refcount looks sufficient to prevent the page from being pushed out, invalidated or migrated; thus safe for dma-type operations.   Migration is discussed in Documentation/vm/page_migrate; the others require spelunking in the vm code.  The short version is that to push a page requires getting all of its references dropped.

Notice that refcount and mapcount are different notions -- mapcount just means somebody has a virtual reference to it; refcount means they have an actual reference to it.  A swapped out page can have a large mapcount.

Also note that as of https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/11/25/684 there is a less obscure interface for this.

Comment: Hi @mevets, does this mean that regular RAM in a user processes never takes a refcount on a struct page?

Comment: From what I saw (I am a many kernel nerd; linux & windows aren't among them); refcount != 0 means there are pending operations on this page, so you can only update certain parts.   Reading the pte is useless, it is just a projection of the info stored in the page structure.

Comment: I tried to edit the post a diagram of the relationship between physical mem, pages, vnodes and mappings.  I did everyone a favour and deleted it.  There is a myriad of abstractions between the program notion of regular RAM and the implementation within a kernel.

Comment: If you change your mind, feel free to post that diagram anyway. For joe schmoes like me, any little bit of extra info helps a lot