# How does get_user_pages() pin a process page in Linux?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I am trying to pin a Linux process page by using get_user_pages() function in kernel. (I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Linux-4.4.0).
But I am not clear, how does get_user_pages() pin the process page, or how does that *pin* mean in the funtion's description.
I did following test to check if the page is pinned.
1. A process, called aligned_alloc(0x1000, 0x1000) to allocation a 4KB memory.
2. A kernel module, which will receive a virtual address from a process by ioctl().
3. Once the virtual address is received in kernel module, it is used to call get_user_pages() like this,
 res = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, vaddr, 1, 1, 1, &page);
4. The process is sleeping for hours, for me to check the status.

With above steps, from /proc/pid/maps, /proc/pid/smaps, and /proc/meminfo, I could NOT find the locking (or pinning) of the process's virtual address.

I also checked the ref_count of the page struct for the process virtual address, before and after call get_user_pages(), the ref_count is the same (3 in my test case), like below.

```
[ 7159.432196] Before, page flag = ffff800004004c, count=3
[ 7159.432196] Pinned Got mmaped.
[ 7159.432197] After, page flags = ffff800004004c, count = 3
```

Did I miss something?

And how does get_user_pages() pin the process pages?
I found a similar question in SO, [How do "pinned" pages in Linux present (or actually "pin") themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931940/how-do-pinned-pages-in-linux-present-or-actually-pin-themselves), but no answers.