# How to know whether a page is/may be used for DMA?

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel, dma

I want to track the pages that are/may be used for DMA.

I only know a page for DMA is "locked" and its physical position is not allowed to change in the main memory. But how can I tell whether a page is "locked" or not? (using flags in struct page, I guess) Or are there better ways to know whether a page is used for DMA?

Comment: Any page may be used for DMA generally speaking, what’s exactly your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but, from what I read here and there, there's no way to know whether a page is used for DMA or not. Like you said, in the page struct there is the flags field which is an unsigned long. In this flags field, there is the locked bit which tells to Linux to not swap a page out of main memory. The best way to know that would be to cross all processes and their address space and check if the page is locked in main memory or not. Normally, it is the device driver which locks the pages. This is necessary to avoid the device writing to a physical address that is not accessible via a virtual address by the calling process. If the device driver doesn't lock the pages, the device will write into a physical frame that could be swapped out or change vm mapping which would be catastrophic. That method also doesn't tell you the kernel's dma. The kernel can sometimes do dma IO like when swapping pages.

Comment: Thanks @user123, but how can I tell a page is "locked" in the physical memory, i.e., it won't be swapped out or migrated. This post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931940/how-do-pinned-pages-in-linux-present-or-actually-pin-themselves) shows holding a refcount to the struct page pins the corresponding physical page. Are there other circumstances?

Comment: If is has the locked bit set I guess. And if refcount > 0. Something like that. The kernel probably doesn't count the pages that are doing DMA. In itself, this count is useless to the kernel. I don't see why you need this count.