# How can I know a page is pinned from the struct page?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, kernel, dma

I want to know whether a page is pinned in the physical memory, i.e., not swappable or migratable.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931940/how-do-pinned-pages-in-linux-present-or-actually-pin-themselves), I know get_user_pages() is commonly used to pin userspace memory in drivers to do DMA. It increases the refcnt of the struct page, which means somebody is operating on the physical page and the page should not be operated.

Are there other circumstances, like memory allocated by "kmalloc" or "vmmaloc" are used for DMA and should be pinned.

Comment: Any page can be used for DMA, it’s unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to ensure a page is *pinned* while it is being DMA-ed.

To examine whether a page is pinned in userspace, Linux offers a set of interfaces called `pagemap` to examine the page tables. See [the doc](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt) (Do read the doc carefully).

The way to test whether a page is DMA-able (pinned) is:

1. Get the pid of current process via `getpid()`.
2. Get the *pfn (page frame number)* of a virtual address from `/proc/<pid>/pagemap`.
3. Query the flags of this page frame from `/proc/kpageflags`. A pinned page has the `UNEVICTABLE` flag on.